# Blackfire unabled to create a network stream on Windows with WAMP

Tags: php, symfony, curl, profiling, blackfire

I'm trying to profile an HTTP Request using Blackfire. I have installed these elements:

- blackfire-agent and its config file (with my server id)
- blackfire client and I configured it with (my client id) (I launched `C:\Users\a.t>blackfire config`)
- blackfire php probe (the dll, the php.ini was edited with my server id)

But I still catch an error:

`C:\Users\a.t>blackfire curl --resolve 'simdate.dev:80:127.0.0.1' http://simdate.dev/`

> Are you authorized to profile this page? No probe response, missing PHP extension or invalid signature for relaying agent.

- Xdebug and other debugging extensions are disabled in the php.ini file
- Client ID and Client Key are different from Server ID and Server Key.
- Blackfire Agent is running too (I had the same error if I stop it)

Here is my log file from the declared log file in php:

```
Sat Mar 11 12:31:44 2017 (11080): [Info] Can't find pgsql module, Blackfire SQL analyzer will be disabled for pgsql SQL queries
Sat Mar 11 12:31:44 2017 (11080): [Info] Can't find oci module, Blackfire SQL analyzer will be disabled for oci SQL queries
Sat Mar 11 12:31:58 2017 (11080): [Debug] Found signature : RWQUOK8z****************iNQE=
Sat Mar 11 12:31:58 2017 (11080): [Info] No key found in memory or key expired, continuing without validation
Sat Mar 11 12:31:58 2017 (11080): [Debug] Found valid agent id
Sat Mar 11 12:31:58 2017 (11080): [Debug] Found file based probe stream (utcp://127.0.0.1:8307)
Sat Mar 11 12:31:58 2017 (11080): [Warning] Unable to create a network stream
```

Here is my log output from the blackfire-agent. As you can see it seems that he never catch connection:

```
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: blackfire-agent 1.9.2 windows amd64 gc 2016-12-14T10:46:38+0000
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Retrieving public keys from API
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Fetching public keys from API
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Sending request GET https://blackfire.io/agent-api/v1/public-keys
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: API answered with status code: 200
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Unmarshalled json result: &{[{RWQUOK8z--------------------------Ac= 20170426}]}
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Started verification of '1' public keys
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Retrieving specs from the API
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Fetching specs from API
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Sending request GET https://blackfire.io/agent-api/v1/specs
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: API answered with status code: 200
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Merging spec from the API and local spec
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: New value of DefaultSpec.LastMaxAge:  24h0m0s
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Listening for connections on 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8307'
[2017-03-11T12:43:03+01:00] DEBUG: Waiting for new connection
```

Here are two screenshots

The first one to show the disabled Xdebug
[image: XDebug is disabled]
The second one to show my blackfire php config (xxxx and yyyy are factice values for the screenshot)[image: phpinfo informations]

Windows Firewall has been disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in your php.ini configuration, you should use `tcp://127.0.0.1:8307` instead of `utcp://127.0.0.1:8307` (note the `utcp` / `tcp` typo) for the `blackfire.agent_socket` value

Comment: Thank your very much Romain, you saved me a lot of time!